# Android: Error Code Explanation?

Tags: android, debugging, android-intent

I have been trying to fix the following error code for so long and can't work it out. What is the cause of this error in my app? Could it also be something wrong with the manifest?

```
  [2014-04-02 23:44:32 - Multapply] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.multapply/.Splash }
    [2014-04-02 23:44:32 - Multapply] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Splash Activity that is being referred to in the error/warning above:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    // set up vars
    MediaPlayer song;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // setting the layout of activity to relate to splash.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        // setting up media player object
        song = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splash);
        song.start();

        Thread timer = new Thread() {

            // Method that firstly starts the thread and makes it sleep, then
            // using
            // intents opens the main activity (usings refernce to its name, see
            // manifest)
            public void run() {

                try {

                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // exceptions caught in here
                    e.printStackTrace(); // useful for debugging

                } finally {

                    Intent openMenu = new Intent("com.example.multapply.menu");
                    startActivity(openMenu);

                }
            }

        };

        timer.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        //finishes activity
        finish();
        //releases song
        song.release();
    }

}// class end
```

Comment: It is not an error, it is a warning. It is telling you that no new `Activity` was started, instead the current `Activity` was brought to the front of the stack.

Comment: Your posted logcat isn't actually showing an error, it's rather a Warning

Comment: What activity wasnt started? The app doesnt actually run at the minute ?

Comment: `com.example.multapply/.Splash` is the `Activity` in question.

Comment: If i edit the post with the splash activity can you take a look at it? Thanks

Comment: Yes but the reason why the app is not loading?

Comment: We will need more stacktrace to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that your app is still running.  Bring up the list of running apps, close yours, and try reloading it from your computer.  In some cases, I've had to uninstall the app and then reinstall it, but it doesn't happen very often.